# NiFi Cluster Docker Load Balancing configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, load-balancing, apache-nifi

I would like to configure Load Balancing in docker-compose.yml file for NiFi cluster deployed via Docker containers.
Current docker-compose parameters for LB are as follows (for each of three NiFi nodes):

```
      # load balancing
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_LOAD_BALANCE_PORT=6342
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_LOAD_BALANCE_HOST=node.name
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_LOAD_BALANCE_CONNECTIONS_PER_NODE=4
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_LOAD_BALANCE_MAX_THREADS=8
```

But, when I try to use load balancing in queues, I can choose all the parameters there, and do not have any error, but LB is not working, everything is done on the primary node (because I used GetSFTP on the primary node only, but want to then process data on all 3 nodes). Also, NiFi cluster is configured to work with SSL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you configure `load balance strategy` on the downstream connection ?

Comment: Yes, I chose the load balance strategy (Round robin) on the queue, but when I check "View status history"  on the processor that follows the queue, all the work is done on the primary node.

Comment: Should ```NIFI_CLUSTER_LOAD_BALANCE_HOST``` be the same on all three nodes, or be different for each node?

Comment: I looked at my docker-compose file and nifi.properties, nifi.cluster.load.balance.host is empty, I hadn't entered any load balance specific variable in my docker-compose file for cluster, just opened the port 6342.  If you want I can share my docker configuration as an answer.

Comment: If it is possible for you, please share your docker-compose.yml configurations. So, you just opened the port and chose the ```load balance strategy``` in a queue, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had opened `load balance port` on my docker file. Also I had to specify `hostname` for each node's compose file

here is my docker file for basic clustering

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  nifi_service:
    container_name: "nifi_service"
    image: "apache/nifi:1.11.4"
    hostname: "APPTHLP7"
    environment:
        - TZ=Europe/Istanbul
        - NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE=true
        - NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT=8088
        - NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING=172.16.2.238:2181,172.16.2.240:2181,172.16.2.241:2181
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        - "8088:8088"
        - "6342:6342" 
    volumes:
        - /home/my/nifi-conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
    networks:
      - my_network
    restart: unless-stopped    
networks:
  my_network:
    external: true
```

please not that you have to configure `load balance strategy` on the downstream connection in your flow.